# A mensagem de erro "Too many pending edits" não foi traduzida

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização

There is an untranslated error message in English when trying to suggest an edit when the queue is full:

[image]

> There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow em Português. Please try again later.

---

(Google Translate)

Há uma mensagem de erro não traduzida em inglês ao tentar sugerir uma edição quando a fila está cheia:

> There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow em Português. Please try again later.

Comment: Traduzido internamente. Na próxima sincronização de strings a tradução ficará disponível. Note que as traduções são feitas pela própria comunidade no https://traducir.win, caso prefira, pode sugerir traduções por lá diretamente. - Translated internally. In the next sync of strings, it will appear online. Please note that here translations are done by the community via http://traducir.win . If you prefer, you can send translation suggestions directly there too.